# Full Text Catalog Issues with text like '1105A-MLKI-KKK-146-'

Tags: sql, full-text-search

Why is there a difference in the below query results -

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"1105A-MLKI-KKK-146-"',
0,--Neutral Language = 0, American English=1033
NULL,--No stop words
0)--Accent Insensitive

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"1105A-MLKI-KKK-146"',
0,--Neutral Language = 0, American English=1033
NULL,--No stop words
0)--Accent Insensitive
```

When there is no difference between the below query results -

```
select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"1105A-MLKI-KKK-ASW-"',
0,--Neutral Language = 0, American English=1033
NULL,--No stop words
0)--Accent Insensitive

select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"1105A-MLKI-KKK-ASW"',
0,--Neutral Language = 0, American English=1033
NULL,--No stop words
0)--Accent Insensitive
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got an update on Microsoft connect that this is an issue with SQL Server word breakers and has been fixed in SQL server 2012. Link for the same is - 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/831986/full-text-search-related-issues

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines for good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer. One of the rules is to add context to links, instead of just pasting them. You should provide an answer that is valid without the need for the user to navigate to another side, but might wish to do so for more detail on the answer. That becomes a bigger problem when the links for some reason become invalid.